# Dynamic checkboxes not posted over form

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql, forms

I have a div element which will auto populate a list of checkboxes on changing a value from another drop down list. The checkboxes are populated fine, however the 'pl' parameter cannot be posted over to the other form, createreport.php on submitting the form.

Entry form:

```
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "loadData.php",
     data: dataString,
     cache: false,
     success: function(result){
       $("#loader").fadeOut(600);
       $("#inputpl").empty().append(result);
     }
   });

    <form action="createreport.php" method="post">
              <div class="form-dropdown" style="width:300px" id="inputpl" name="pl">

    //////////checkboxes populated here. If I hard code the checkboxes here, it can be passed over successfully

              </div>
    <input type="submit" />
    </form>
```

loadData.php:

```
for($i=0; $i<=odbc_fetch_row($result); $i++){
                $name = odbc_result($result, 1);


                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="pl[]" value="'.$name.'" />'.$name.'<br/>';
            }
```

createreport.php:

```
  echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_POST['pl']);
    echo '</pre>';
```

Output:

Notice:  Undefined index: pl in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\createreport.php on line 21

EDIT: I am able to alert the value of the checkboxes by adding this to the submit button:

```
  $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
        alert(this.value);
    })
```

Comment: Are you checking any checkboxes before submitting the form? You should handle the case of zero checked boxes with `if (!empty($_POST['pl']))`

Comment: What kind of data is in `dataString` and why are you using `odbc_fetch_row`?

Comment: Just string data. That's because I'm fetching the checkbox values from odbc

Comment: @user1033038 Checkboxes are not populated inside your form. can you show the full code?

Comment: This is pretty much the full code. Checkboxes are populated correctly.

Comment: Here's what I think might have caused this. When I click view source in browser, the input boxes were not visible in the codes. Hence, I believe this is the reason why the checkboxes cannot be posted over.

Comment: Please view source and edit your post with the resulting html.

Answer (score 1):

```
for($i=0; $i<=odbc_fetch_row($result); $i++){
    $name = odbc_result($result, 1);
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="pl[]" value="'.$name.'" />'.$name.'<br/>';
}
```

`odbc_fetch_row` returns a boolean for a successful fetch. You want this:

```
<?php
while (odbc_fetch_row($result)) {
    $name = odbc_result($result, 1);
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="pl[]" value="'.$name.'" />'.$name.'<br/>';
}
```

It doesn't look like anything would have been returned from loadData.php anyway.

Comment: Still the same error. loadData returns a list of values from the db

Answer (score 0):

I think you have submit the form without checking any checkboxes thats why the error is reported

please try following code

```
if(isset($_POST['pl'])){
echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_POST['pl']);
    echo '</pre>';
    }
```

Comment: I've ensured that the checkboxes are checked